# Get the identifier

Tags: javascript

At the starting I must tell that I am a newbie and sorry for a such a silly question
Second that `.extract` is just an example.

Here is the code

```
String.prototype.extract=function(start,end){
     var value=this;
     var rval="";
     for(var i=start; i<=end; i++){
          rval+=value.charAt(i)
     }
     ????? = rval;
}

var str="abcdef";
str.extract(1,4)
alert(str) //must be bcde
```

Now I want the caller of method extract (str) and the value of rval must be saved to that only.

I could do it by: 
`str = str.extract;`
and in the function `return rval`

but I want that like we do it as `something.toUpperCase` instead of `something=something.toUpperCase`

????? must be replaced by the caller of method extract (str)

any help would be useful

Comment: Strings (more general: all values of primitive types) are immutable. There is no way around it (unless you implement your own JavaScript engine I guess).

Comment: ^ What he said, and `toUpperCase` does not change the string "in place" it returns a new string, like any other string method.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to handle this is with a callback.

Re-using your code, it would look like:

```
String.prototype.extract=function(start,end, callback){
     var value=this;
     var rval="";
     for(var i=start; i<=end; i++){
          rval+=value.charAt(i)
     }
     callback(rval);
}

var str="abcdef";
str.extract(1,4, function(s1) {
    alert(s1) //must be bcde
});
```

Another way to handle it would be to simply return the value and re-assign it to the original variable.

```
String.prototype.extract=function(start,end, callback){
     var value=this;
     var rval="";
     for(var i=start; i<=end; i++){
          rval+=value.charAt(i)
     }
     return rval;
}

var str="abcdef";
str = str.extract(1,4);
alert(str) //must be bcde
```

Comment: Why on earth would you use a callback for a synchronous method ?

Comment: Why would you use a callback here? This is synchronous code and I would not expect a callback here. Look at the other String methods.

Comment: I would use a callback because I felt that best matched the control flow he is after.  Yes, he could use a regular return there and I'll update my answer.